# terraform How to use conditional if in for_each into map object

Tags: terraform

I have maps of variables like this:

users.tfvars

```
users = {
  "testterform" = {
    path          = "/"
    force_destroy = true
    email_address = "testterform@example.com"
    group_memberships = [ "test1" ]
    tags = { department : "test" }
    ssh_public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA4l7"
  }

  "testterform2" = {
    path          = "/"
    force_destroy = true
    email_address = "testterform2@example.com"
    group_memberships = [ "test1" ]
    tags = { department : "test" }
    ssh_public_key = ""
  }
```

I would like to upload ssh key only if `ssh_public_key` not empty for the user. But don't understand how to check this

#main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "this" {
  for_each = var.users

  name                 = each.key
  path                 = each.value["path"]
  force_destroy        = each.value["force_destroy"]

  tags = merge(each.value["tags"], { Provisioner : var.provisioner, EmailAddress : each.value["email_address"] })
}

resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "this" {
  for_each = var.users

  user   = each.key
  groups = each.value["group_memberships"]

  depends_on = [ aws_iam_user.this ]
}

resource "aws_iam_user_ssh_key" "this" {

  for_each = var.users

  username = each.key
  encoding = "SSH"
  public_key = each.value["ssh_public_key"]

  depends_on = [ aws_iam_user.this ]
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It sounds like what you need here is a derived "users that have non-empty SSH keys" map. You can use the `if` clause of a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) to derive a new collection from an existing one while filtering out some of the elements:

```
resource "aws_iam_user_ssh_key" "this" {
  for_each = {
    for name, user in var.users : name => user
    if user.ssh_public_key != ""
  }

  username   = each.key
  encoding   = "SSH"
  public_key = each.value.ssh_public_key

  depends_on = [aws_iam_user.this]
}
```

The derived map here uses the same keys and values as the original `var.users`, but is just missing some of them. That means that the `each.key` results will correlate and so you'll still get the same `username` value you were expecting, and your instances will have addresses like `aws_iam_user_ssh_key.this["testterform"]`.

Comment: This answer perfectly fits my needs, thanks

Comment: We've reorganized the expressions docs to be less scroll-y. For anyone looking, the new page on for expressions is [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html).

Comment: Perfect for my need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop to exclude those blanks.
For example, you can do it on local:

```
variable "users" {
  default = {
    "testterform" = {
      path           = "/"
      force_destroy  = true
      tags           = { department : "test" }
      ssh_public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA4l7"
    }
    "testterform2" = {
      path           = "/"
      force_destroy  = true
      tags           = { department : "test" }
      ssh_public_key = ""
    }
  }
}

locals {
  public_key = flatten([
    for key, value in var.users : 
      value.ssh_public_key if ! contains([""], value.ssh_public_key)
  ])
}

output "myout" {
  value = local.public_key
}
```

that will output:

```
myout = [
  "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA4l7",
]
```

As you can see the empty ones have been removed, and you can add other stuff you want to exclude on that contains array.
Then you can use that `local.public_key` in the `for_each` for your ssh keys

Comment: is not exactly what I need, but you gave me an idea for another case. Thank you.